# Data Validation: Text length + restrict some CHARACTERS in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel,using data validation I want to restrict one cell like below

1-**Minimum length should be 3 and Maximum length should be 7**

and

2-**Restrict user that he/she cannot enter some characters say** " : and ? "

Kindly provide the formula.

Thanks

Comment: You cant restrict Cell A with a formula in Cell A - you need vba for that

Comment: What formula have you tried under validation yourself?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this formula:

```
=AND(LEN(D5)>2,LEN(D5)<8,NOT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(":",D5))))
```

For other characters you have to add extra `NOT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(`-instances.